# How to covert 1d array to Logical matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Is there any bulid-in function in python/numpy to convert an `array = [1, 3, 1, 2]` to something like this:

```
array = [[0, 1, 0, 0], 
        [0, 0, 0, 1], 
        [0, 1, 0, 0], 
        [0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: I think that this 2D array called binary matrix or Logical matrix

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create an identity matrix and then use the indices to create a new re-ordered matrix:

```
>>> a = np.eye(4)
[Out]: array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0., 1., 0., 0.],
              [0., 0., 1., 0.],
              [0., 0., 0., 1.]])

>>> indices = [1, 3, 1, 2]
>>> a[indices]
[Out]: array([[0., 1., 0., 0.],
              [0., 0., 0., 1.],
              [0., 1., 0., 0.],
              [0., 0., 1., 0.]])
```

Comment: That young man, you nailed it!

Answer (score 3):

Probably the fastest would be to allocate zeros and then set the ones:

```
>>> def f_preall(a):
...    m, n = a.size, a.max()+1
...    out = np.zeros((m, n))
...    out[np.arange(m), a] = 1
...    return out
... 
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>>
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 10, (10,))
>>> timeit(lambda: f_preall(a), number=10000)
0.04905537283048034
>>> timeit(lambda: np.eye(a.max()+1)[a], number=10000)
0.09359440207481384
>>>
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 100, (100,))
>>> timeit(lambda: f_preall(a), number=10000)
0.10055362526327372
>>> timeit(lambda: np.eye(a.max()+1)[a], number=10000)
0.16951417503878474
```